# join bash remaining parameters from arg 3 onwards

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to join and send the remaining parameters for a script to a command.  Eg:

```
if [ "$2" == "exec" ]; then
    other_script execute "$3 $4 $5 $6 $7 (etc etc etc)"
fi
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`bash` array slice notation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams#range_of_positional_parameters):

```
foo() {
    echo "[$1]"
    echo "[$2]"
    echo "[${@:3}]"
}
```

Produces:

```
$ foo a b c d ef
[a]
[b]
[c d ef]
```

Which you would implement in your code as:

```
if [ "$2" == "exec" ]; then
    other_script execute "${@:3}"
fi
```

If you needed say the 3rd and 4th arguments, you could apply a length to the slice:

```
other_script execute "${@:3:2}" # :2 is a length specification
```

Another way, if you didn't need arguments `$1` or `$2` any longer, is to just shift them out of the way:

```
foo=${1:?Missing argument one}
bar=${2:-Default}
shift 2

echo "$@" # the first two args are gone, so this is now args #3 on
```

I prefer this way, honestly, for a couple of reasons:

1. Numbered args are hard to remember: named args are more clear.
2. The array slice notation isn't well-known (based on my experience), so it may cause some confusion with future maintenance.

Comment: I really like the detail of this great answer!